# How to add values into a variable of type object in C#

Tags: c#, object, generics, dictionary

Now I'am this is what actual code looks like, which is debugging(running) successfully:

```
object attributes = new object[] { 
                  "key1=value1",
                  "key2=value2",
                  "key3=value3",
                  "key4=value4",
                  "keyN=valueN" 
};
```

I need to change the values sometimes, so I am using C# Dictionary which is defined as:

```
public Dictionary<string,string> dAttributes=new Dictionary<string,string>();
```

I am adding the KEY and VALUE in the dictionary one by one. But when I try to typecast(which I think is not possible) or apply any other logic, the values in the object named "attributes" are not getting in proper format.

First I tried this:

```
object attributes = new object[]{dAttributes};
```

Then I did this:

```
            int i=0;
            string attribueKeyAndValues;
            attribueKeyAndValues = "";
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string,string> item in dAttributes)
            {
                if(i==(dealAttributes.Count-1))
                    attribueKeyAndValues+="\"" +item.Key+"="+item.Value+"\"";
                else
                    attribueKeyAndValues += "\"" + item.Key +"="+ item.Value + "\"" + ",";
                i++;
            }

            attributes = new object[] { attribueKeyAndValues };
```

Now this code is not working because `attribute` is taking the entire string as a single value. Plus more important thing is when I debug the code and quick watch the value in `attribueKeyAndValues` (in Text Visualizer) is shows me `"\key=value\","\key=value\"` and so on.

Is there any other way to add the values in the `attribute`?

Comment: of course it's not working, because attributeKeyAndValue is a single string and not an array of string.
Keep also in mind that if you foreaching a Dictionary the order is not guaranteed.

Comment: Hmm, seems some major weirdness here. Why are you starting with an `object` that's referencing an `object[]` which itself only contain strings? Why are you not starting out with `string[]` and eschewing `object` entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

conversion from dictionary to array

```
attributes = dAttributes.Select(a=>a.Key+"="+a.Value).ToArray();
```

here a co-variant array conversion is used (`ToArray()` returns `string[]`, but it can be assigned to `object[]` variable)

but if you really need `object[]`, make a cast

```
attributes = dAttributes.Select(a=>(object)(a.Key+"="+a.Value)).ToArray();
```

then something like `attributes[0] = 1;` will work
(in the 1st method that will throw run-time exception)

Comment: @phoog, `object[] o = new string[4];` is co-variant array conversion; `attributes` can be `object[]`. it is possible to use `attributes[0]="string"` but `attributes[0]=1` throws run-time exception

Comment: Agreed.  The original example, however, does not use covariant array conversion, and `attributes[0]=1` would not throw an exception.  Your solution therefore is not equivalent to the example code.

Comment: that worked, then I just tried this following code I posted here. thanks a lot :)

Comment: @phoog, indeed. i added more details to the answer

Comment: But why do all that casting when you can just call `ToArray<object>()`?

Comment: @phoog I did the same, check my answer. and

Comment: @ASh yes, I'am did, but this casting is allowing me to return an object. That was the actual problem. And your answer helped to solve this

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to copy keys and values from a dictionary into an array of strings.  Your last code example creates a single string, but a small modification will fix it:

```
int i=0;
var attributes = new object[dAttributes.Count];
string attribueKeyAndValues = "";
foreach (KeyValuePair<string,string> item in dAttributes)
{
    result[i] = item.Key + "=" + item.Value;
    i++;
}
```

As an aside, you might be better off using a string array instead of an object array:

```
int i=0;
var attributes = new string[dAttributes.Count];
string attribueKeyAndValues = "";
foreach (KeyValuePair<string,string> item in dAttributes)
{
    result[i] = item.Key + "=" + item.Value;
    i++;
}
```

Finally, you can do this using LINQ:

```
var attributes = dAttributes.Select(item => item.Key + "=" + item.Value).ToArray();
```

Or, if you really need it to be an object array instead of a string array, you can do this:

```
var attributes = dAttributes.Select(item => item.Key + "=" + item.Value).ToArray<object>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at dynamic objects, where you can add whatever you want however you want (well, with the usual caveats).

You can find more about them here

- [ExpandoObject Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

  - [Expando Objects in C# 4.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff796227.aspx)

You can then do things like:

```
dynamic sampleObject = new ExpandoObject();
sampleObject.number = 10;
sampleObject.Increment = (Action)(() => { sampleObject.number++; });
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, with the help of ASH's answer I worked out it successfully with one more friend of mine,

```
public static class AttributeExtensions
    {
        public static object ToAttributeArray(this DAttributes dealAttr)
        {
            var objectsColl = dealAttr.dAttributes.Select(x => x.Key + "=" + x.Value);

            var objArray = objectsColl.Cast<object>();
            return  objArray.ToArray<object>();

        }
    }
```

Now its working properly, thanks you guys :)